# How to remove/shift an element from the middle of an array in Python using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose the array is [1,2,3,4]. I want to make this array like this [1,3,4,None].
Explanation: I want to remove 2 and insert None at the end of the array. Help me using just only numpy and basic loop, (Not using remove, pop)

Thanks for any help, feel free to give advice

```
import numpy as np

def shift(arr):
    
    for i in range(0,len(arr)-1):
        if arr[i] == 2:
            arr[i] = arr[i+1]
    #arr[len(arr)-1] = None <--- this line also giving error 
    return arr

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print(shift(arr))
```

Comment: How do you remove `2`? by value?

Answer (score 0):

###### [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

Don't loop! Use a boolean mask for indexing, then [`pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

mask = arr == 2
out = np.pad(arr[~mask].astype(float), (0, mask.sum()), constant_values=np.nan)
```

Variant with [`r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) and [`full`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html):

```
mask = arr == 2
out = np.r_[arr[~mask], np.full(mask.sum(), np.nan)]
```

Output: `array([ 1.,  3.,  4.,  5., nan])`

###### pure python

```
lst = [1,2,3,2,2,4,5]

idx = 0
for value in lst:
    if value!=2:
        lst[idx] = value
        idx += 1
lst[idx:] = [None]*(len(lst)-idx)
```

Output: `[1, 3, 4, 5, None, None, None]`